# Create a 1-n from an array of objects

Tags: typescript, prisma

I was wondering if someone could please help me with this.  I have spent a while searching the web but could not find anything.  I am only learning to program and I am stuck.

I am trying to create a 1-n relationship.  The 1 is the Business, the n is from the data from the array of objects.

I would like to:

1. Create the Business
2. Create the Trading Entities and link them to the Business.  The TradingEntity.name comes from BN_NAME, TradingEntity.Status from BN_STATUS

I am using NestJS but any help in typescript would be great as I will try to learn from that.

Thanks for your help.

-Paul

My schema is:

```
model Business {
  id                Int                          @id @default(autoincrement())
  BN_ABN            Int?                         @unique
  tradingEntities   TradingEntity[]
}

model TradingEntity {
  id                Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  Business          Business       @relation(fields: [BusinessId], references: [id])
  BusinessId        Int
  Name              String         //  BN_NAME from array of objects 
  Status            String         //  BN_STATUS from array of objects
}
```

This is the array of objects.

```
[
  {
    _id: 1812602,
    REGISTER_NAME: 'BUSINESS NAMES',
    BN_NAME: 'Synergy Evolved',
    BN_STATUS: 'Registered',
    BN_REG_DT: '08/09/2012',
    BN_CANCEL_DT: null,
    BN_RENEW_DT: '08/09/2021',
    BN_STATE_NUM: null,
    BN_STATE_OF_REG: null,
    BN_ABN: '48166724204',
    rank: 0.0573088
  },
  {
    _id: 2199676,
    REGISTER_NAME: 'BUSINESS NAMES',
    BN_NAME: 'VALUERACK',
    BN_STATUS: 'Registered',
    BN_REG_DT: '11/04/2012',
    BN_CANCEL_DT: null,
    BN_RENEW_DT: '11/04/2015',
    BN_STATE_NUM: 'B2460084Y',
    BN_STATE_OF_REG: 'VIC',
    BN_ABN: '48166724204',
    rank: 0.0573088
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the array of objects to create *both* the `Business` and `TradingEntity` records using a single Prisma query. To do this, you will need to use the [connecOrCreate API](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#connectorcreate).

Here is a solution to insert the data in the array of objects into your database.

```js
// Assuming executing inside an async function
// Assuming array of objects is stored in a variable called "businessData"

for (const data of businessData) {
    const tradingEntity = await prisma.tradingEntity.create({
        data: {
            Name: data.BN_NAME,
            Status: data.BN_STATUS,
            Business: {
                connectOrCreate: {
                    /*
                    * Will connect to an existing "Business" record with matching BN_ABN if it exists,
                    * OR
                    * Will create a new "Business" record if there is no existing record with a matching BN_ABN.
                    */
                    where: {
                        BN_ABN: parseInt(data.BN_ABN)  //BN_ABN is a string in the object, so converted to Int to comply with Prisma Schema.
                    },
                    create: {
                        BN_ABN: parseInt(data.BN_ABN)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Given the array of objects you provided, the above snippet will

1. Create two `TradingEntity` records with *names* "Synergy Evolved" and "VALUERACK".
2. Create one `Business` record with a *BN_ABN* of 922083948.

Optionally, you should consider changing the field names in `TradingEntity` from PascalCase to camelCase. This is better aligned with the [naming conventions](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference/#naming-conventions) suggested in the Prisma Docs.